# How to center multiple images horizontally both left & right inside parent with hidden overflow

Tags: css, image, overflow, center

I have 50 small images in a wrapper. I want the images to appear horizontally on the same line with hidden overflow.  It works BUT the images start from the left.

How do I make overflow both LEFT and RIGHT with the starting point in the middle rather than the left?

Here is my code:

```css
.whoARRAY {
  width: 100%;
  height: 90px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}

.whoARRAY img {}
```

```html
<div class="whoARRAY"><img src="https://www.young-marines.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/ym_017.png" /><img src="https://www.young-marines.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/ym_016.png" /><img src="https://www.young-marines.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/ym_015.png" /><img src="https://www.young-marines.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/ym_014.png"
  /><img src="https://www.young-marines.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/ym_013.png" /><img src="https://www.young-marines.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/ym_012.png" /><img src="https://www.young-marines.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/ym_011.png" /><img
    src="https://www.young-marines.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/ym_010.png" /><img src="https://www.young-marines.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/ym_009.png" /><img src="https://www.young-marines.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/ym_010.png" /></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to calculate it via JS.
You can use `scrollWidth` & `offsetWidth` in order to calculate `scrollLeft`.

Pay attention to the `white-space: nowrap`, it makes the images not to wrap inside the container.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
  const elm = document.querySelector('.whoARRAY');
  elm.scrollLeft = elm.scrollWidth / 2 - elm.offsetWidth / 2
});
```

```css
.whoARRAY {
  width: 100%;
  height: 90px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.whoARRAY img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="whoARRAY">
  <img src="https://www.young-marines.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/ym_017.png" />
  <img src="https://www.young-marines.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/ym_016.png" />
  <img src="https://www.young-marines.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/ym_015.png" />
  <img src="https://www.young-marines.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/ym_014.png" />
  <img src="https://www.young-marines.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/ym_013.png" />
  <img src="https://www.young-marines.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/ym_012.png" />
  <img src="https://www.young-marines.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/ym_011.png" />
  <img src="https://www.young-marines.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/ym_010.png" />
  <img src="https://www.young-marines.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/ym_009.png" />
  <img src="https://www.young-marines.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/ym_010.png" /></div>
```